# Trying to install Signal, directory doesn't exist and can't be created

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install Signal, but it gets stuck about 1/3 of the way through. For a while it was giving me an error about not being able to create a file in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\signal-desktop (for some reason that error isn't popping up anymore). When I go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local, I can make a new folder and try to rename it signal-desktop, but it doesn't work. I can rename it to anything else, like "signal-deskto". When I try to rename it to "signal-desktop", it says "you need to confirm this operation." at which point I hit "continue" (with admin privileges), and then it gives an error "you need permission to perform this action" (try again/cancel).

So I suspect that the installer is trying to create that folder and failing for whatever reason. I don't see a hidden folder when I look, so I don't know why it isn't working. Any advice?

I am asking this question here more in hopes of understanding what could be happening in the filesystem, and less interested in getting an answer about the Signal installer, but if I get an answer about that, great.

Here's another way of describing what's happening:

```
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs>dir
     Directory of C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs
    
    11/11/2020  02:49 PM    <DIR>          .
    11/11/2020  02:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
    11/11/2020  02:49 PM    <DIR>          signal-deskto
                   0 File(s)              0 bytes
                   3 Dir(s)  263,202,971,648 bytes free
    
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs>rename signal-deskto signal-desktop
    A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
    
    C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs>mkdir signal-desktop
    A subdirectory or file signal-desktop already exists.

    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs>dir /ah
File not found
```

Comment: MrBarryAllen found a workaround, but I'm still curious what's going on with the filesystem.  https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/jskoo1/cant_install_signal_on_laptop_windows_10/gc26hx5/

Comment: Did you run the installer as administrator? Right click on the installer and choose "run as administrator"

Comment: I did, thank you. No use.